# In SQL server, why is N'' equal to N''?

Tags: sql-server

I don't understand why the following returns 'Equal':

`SELECT IIF(N'✅' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC = N''  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC, 'Equal', 'NotEqual')`

returns `Equal`

I am aware that sql server ignores trailing spaces when comparing strings however I don't understand this result.

Even more bizarre, if I use a different emoji, the result is 'NotEqual':

`SELECT IIF(N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC = N''  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC, 'Equal', 'NotEqual')`

returns `NotEqual`

Edit: I'm aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551528/sql-query-where-column-returning-emoji-characters-and and the fact that the behavior is expected on older, non-100 collations. However I am using a 100 collation here.

Comment: when you use a different emoji, such as `''`, it is not considered equivalent to the empty string. The collation `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC` does not define an equivalence between `''` and an empty `''` string. so, the comparison results in 'NotEqual'.

Comment: What equivalence are you talking about?

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/60222376/14868997 there is no weight assigned for `✅` in that collation. Try `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`